# unixODBC access to MDB databasefile for all users

Tags: security, database, microsoft, restricted-access, odbc

I have configured the odbc for a MS Access MDB databasefile. The access is ok when executing `sudo isql -v MyDatabaseName` since it returns `Connected!` and I get a SQL prompt and I can select data from the database.

But, when executing as a normal (no sudo) user I get this:

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Where is the access managed and how do I give normal users access to the database?

Comment: Could you check if the `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files are readable (from non super users)?  Just try something like `cat /etc/odbc.ini`.